# ¿Como habilitar python en lighttpd manjaroOS?

Tags: python, django, servidor

Buenas tardes amigos de stackoverflow tengo una duda gigante quisiera poder habilitar en mi servidor lighttpd python y si es posible ruby para poder estudiar y realizar pruebas web desde flask y django.

Aqui esta mi codigo de configuración. Postdata de darme un archivo de prueba para correrlo en mi servidor.

```
    server.port     = 80
server.username     = "http"
server.groupname    = "http"
server.document-root    = "/usr/share/www/"
server.errorlog     = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
dir-listing.activate    = "enable"
index-file.names    = ( "index.html" )

mimetype.assign     = (
                ".html" => "text/html",
                ".txt" => "text/plain",
                ".css" => "text/css",
                ".js" => "application/x-javascript",
                ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
                ".jpeg" => "image/jpeg",
                ".gif" => "image/gif",
                ".png" => "image/png",
                "" => "application/octet-stream"
            )
#
cgi.assign                 = ( ".pl"  => "/usr/bin/perl",
                               ".cgi" => "/usr/bin/perl",
                               ".rb"  => "/usr/bin/ruby",
                               ".erb" => "/usr/bin/eruby",
                               ".py"  => "/usr/bin/python",
                               ".php" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi" )
index-file.names           += ( "index.pl",   "default.pl",
                               "index.rb",   "default.rb",
                               "index.erb",  "default.erb",
                               "index.py",   "default.py",
                               "index.php",  "default.php" )
#
include "conf.d/fastcgi.conf"
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema?¿Que no funciona? ¿Tienes habilitados los modulos oportunos en `server.modules` si mal no recuerdo (no lo veo en tu .conf)? Supongo que lo includes en tu fastcgi.conf. Por ejemplo `server.modules = (
            "mod_access",
            "mod_alias",
            "mod_accesslog",
            "mod_auth",
            "mod_ssi",
            "mod_cgi",
            "mod_fastcgi",
)` según tus necesidades. La wiky de ArchLinux suele ser una buena fuente en estos casos :https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/lighttpd

Comment: @FJSevilla pero ya revise la documentación en la sección de python y no tengo ni la mas minima idea de como configurarlo para que me corrar archivos python en mi servidor.